Likelihood ratio test -- Multiparameter multinomial distribution
This is a problem from Hogg and McKean's "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics" (Exercise $6.5.11.$)
Problem Statement
Let $n$ independent trials of an experiment be such that $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$ are
the respective numbers of times that the experiment ends in the mutually exclusive
and exhaustive events $C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_k.$ If $p_i = P(C_i)$ is constant throughout the $n$
trials, then the probability of that particular sequence of trials is $L=p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}\cdots p_k^{x_k}.$
(a) Recalling that $p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_k = 1$, show that the likelihood ratio for testing $H_0 : p_i = p_{i0} > 0, i = 1,2,\ldots, k,$ against all alternatives is given by $$\Lambda = \prod_{i=1}^k \left ( \cfrac{(p_{i0})^{x_i}}{(x_i/n)^{x_i}} \right )$$
(b) Show that $$-2\log{\Lambda} = \sum_{i=1}^k \cfrac{x_i(x_i-np_{i0})^2}{(np'_{i})^2}$$ where $p_i'$ is between $p_{i0}$ and $x_i/n$
Hint: Expand $\log{p_{i0}}$ in a Taylor’s series with the remainder in the term
involving $(p_{i0} − x_i/n)^2.$
(c) For large $n$, argue that $x_i/(np_i')^2$ is approximated by $1/(np_{i0})$ and hence $$-2\log{\Lambda} \approx \sum_{i=1}^{k} \cfrac{(x_i-np_{i0})^2}{np_{i0}}.$$
Theorem $6.5.1$ says that the right-hand member of this last equation defines a statistic that has an approximate chi-square distribution with $k − 1$ degrees of freedom. Note that dimension of $\Omega$ $-$ dimension of $\omega = (k − 1) − 0 = k − 1.$
My attempt:
Part (a) is sort of trivial. I am realy stuck in part (b). Call $q_i = x_i/n$. Using Taylor Series expansion of $\log{p_{i0}}$ about $q_i$, we get
\begin{align}
-2\log{\Lambda} &= -2\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i\left[ \log{p_{i0}} - \log{q_i} \right] \\
&= -2\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\left[ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j} \left ( \cfrac{p_{i0} - q_i}{q_i} \right )^j\right] \\
&= -2\sum_{i=1}^k (np_{i0}-x_i) -2\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\left[ \sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j} \left ( \cfrac{p_{i0} - q_i}{q_i} \right )^j\right] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \cfrac{x_i(x_i-np_{i0})^2}{(nq_i)^2} \left [ 1+2 \sum_{j=3}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j-2}}{j}  \left ( \frac{p_{i0}-q_i}{q_i}\right )^{j-2} \right ].
\end{align}
The last equation uses the facts that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i = n$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{k}p_{i0} = 1$. The expression in the square braces can be clubbed with $q_i^2$ in the denominator to arrive at a form for $p'_i$. But then we need to show that this is between $p_{i0}$ and $q_i$.
I thought of using mean value theorem as soon as I read "in between" ... It's a dead end there. MVT assures existence of some $p'_i$ such that $$\log{p_{i0}} - \log{q_i} = \frac{p_{i0}-q_i}{p'_i},$$ such that it lies between $p_{i0}$ and $q_i$. But no matter how much of algebra I tried, I could not arrive at the relationship that they ask for in part (b).
I'd greatly appreciate it if you can help me out with this exercise problem.
Update (July $19^{\textrm{th}}$, morning $2024$):
So basically the part (b) claims that $p_i'^2$ obtained through Taylor expansion (whose steps are shown above and which can be massaged in the form below), lies between $p^2_{i0}$ and $q_i^2$.
$$\begin{align}
p'^2_i &= \cfrac{q_i^2}{\left [ 1+2 \sum_{j=3}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j-2}}{j}  \left ( \frac{p_{i0}-q_i}{q_i}\right )^{j-2} \right ]}\\
&=\cfrac{(p_{i0}-q_i)^2}{2 \left( \frac{p_{i0}-q_i}{q_i} - (\log{p_{i0}-\log{q_i}}) \right)}.
\end{align}$$
As $\min{(p_{i0}^2,q_i^2)} < p'^2_i <\max{(p_{i0}^2,q_i^2)}$, we have the following neat condition:
$$\min{(p_{i0}^2,q_i^2)} < \cfrac{(p_{i0}-q_i)^2}{2 \left( \frac{p_{i0}-q_i}{q_i} - (\log{p_{i0}-\log{q_i}}) \right)} <\max{(p_{i0}^2,q_i^2)}.$$
Now I have not been able to prove this, but I was atleast able to run a small python code to check if this is indeed true when we take two arbitrary numbers in $(0,1)$ to check if this inequality holds.

cnt = 0

while(cnt < 3000):
    p=random.uniform(0,1)
    q=random.uniform(0,1)
    pp = (p-q)**2/2/((p-q)/q - (np.log(p) - np.log(q)))
    if((min(p**2,q**2) < pp < max(p**2,q**2)) == False):
        print(p,q)
        break
    else:
        cnt = cnt+1


I ran this code multiple times and could not find a single pair $(p,q)$ that violated the "conjecture". So it definitely looks like the claim $\min{(p_{i0},q_i)} < p'_i <\max{(p_{i0},q_i)}$ is true based on this empirical search. I thought of sharing it with you guys.
Update (July $19^{\textrm{th}}$, afternoon $2024$):
I am sure many of you were watching this and laughing at me making a fool of myself! :) This is indeed a direct application of Taylor Series expansion except that there is a "Lagrange Form" of Taylor series which gives a definitive form for the remainder.
So here, using the Lagrange Form, we get
\begin{equation}
\log{p_{i0}} = \log{q_i}+\frac{p_{i0}-q_i}{q_i}-\frac{1}{2}\cfrac{(p_{i0}-q_i)^2}{p'^2_i},
\end{equation}
where $\min{(p_{i0},q_i)} < p'_i <\max{(p_{i0},q_i)}$. Essentially the remainder form of Taylor series which is called the Lagrange Form gives us the desired $p'_i$.
In case you guys still see an issue, I'd appreciate it if you can let me know.

To reduce the notation, it might be simpler to show this for single terms $$-2[\log(p) - \log(q)]= (p-q)^2/r^2 $$ with $r$ between $p$ and $q$. Or differently use
$$r^2 = \frac{0.5 (p-q)^2}{[\log(q) - \log(p)]}$$

That will do it even though I am not sure how that can be done. His hint specifically mentions Taylor series expansion on $\log{p_{i0}}$ but that does not directly provide the existence of the desired $p'_i$ the way mean value theorem does. But the $p'_i$ we get through MVT does not give us the desired expression. So I wonder what the author had in his mind when he gave the hint.

On second thought, it doesn't work to prove it for the terms separately. The logarithm term can be negative whereas the square terms are always positive.
